# Is it possible to record browser screen pragmatically?

Tags: javascript, browser, recording

I have a scenario that :

I have a web application and i want that whenever user opens the application, whatever the activity he will do in the application i.e. mouse moving, writing from keyboead and it will appear in text box,etc, it must be record pragmatically.

[Screenr](http://www.screenr.com/)

does the same thing but it is an application. I want this thing using code.

I have searched it but did not find any solution. Please help me solve out this issue.

Comment: Check this [link](http://ctrlq.org/code/19136-screenshots-javascript) it uses javascript userAgent and generates png files

Comment: I sure would hope that any such thing would record things *sensibly and realistically in a way that's based on practice*... ;-P

Comment: @bios. It gives png images. I need recording in video format

Comment: Using javascript only is hard... (I think impossible, due to privacy restrictions). The website screenr uses java, which can do much more. The privacy thing is because you wont want a particular web page to record your screen without you even knowing it. You can however save the data of a canvas using `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` and later on create a video from all the pictures, but that is probably not what you want

Comment: @MarijnS95 Yes You are right. Its too typical. I have searched a lot but did not found any feasible solution.

Comment: @Rishi But now I think about it, if you would send any change in the page, like a button click or something, you can generate a screen capture. Use mousemove events to detect the current mouse location and render an image of that on the other computer. - So this means that you don't get image data, but you can record all changes, and dynamically generate a video from it.